# Android 3.0 Starter Pack - XML Verification Error

Tags: android

I have recently downloaded the SDK starter pack 'android-sdk_r10-windows' for Android development. I have Windows Vista OS. But now when I am starting the SDK Manager to install the Platform tools i am getting the below erorrs -

---

XML verification failed for https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml.
Line -१:-१, Error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'null', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .

XML verification failed for https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list.xml.

### Line -१:-१, Error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'null', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .

I also tried the Force settings in Settings -> Misc, but it too didn't help.

Can someone throw some pointers. I am a bit stuck as I have downloaded the Starter pack and not able to figure out what could be wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no pointers from anyone ... no one else faced this issue with the Android 3.0 starter pack?

Comment: finally i was able to resolve the issue :).

Comment: Please post the solution If you have already fixed this

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem in eclipse as well as android studio and i was able to solve it by changing the computer language. check your computer language and set only English language in your computer.